# How to include No of members in Cluster in ggplot2 plot and choose different colour scheme for different clusters

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data that looks like this , basically its transaction amounts , which cluster it belongs to and the smallest cluster amongst them .

```
   TranAmount   whichCLuster    smallestCluster
  1:     344.96            3               4
  2:     244.15            3               4
  3:     342.23            3               4
  4:      44.77            3               4
  5:    8052.48            1               4
  6:     184.78            3               4
  7:      11.19            3               4
  8:    1355.71            3               4
  9:    1162.07            3               4
 10:     461.95            3               4
 11:      83.97            3               4
 12:     344.37            3               4
 13:     648.03            3               4
 14:    2122.39            2               4
 15:     295.29            3               4
 16:     474.32            3               4
 17:    2111.72            2               4
 18:     950.63            3               4
 19:    1246.47            3               4
 20:     138.79            3               4
 21:     917.79            3               4
 22:     112.00            3               4
 23:     378.65            3               4
 24:      47.57            3               4
 25:    5610.00            2               4
 26:    1453.69            3               4
 27:    1058.01            3               4
 28:     955.77            3               4
 29:     277.07            3               4
 30:     861.53            3               4
 31:     296.76            3               4
 32:     465.04            3               4
 33:     159.65            3               4
 34:    3625.25            2               4
 35:     197.08            3               4
 36:     162.38            3               4
 37:    1460.08            3               4
 38:     438.74            3               4
 39:     564.15            3               4
 40:     389.44            3               4
 41:    1924.62            2               4
 42:     190.39            3               4
 43:     565.41            3               4
 44:      78.39            3               4
 45:    2926.92            2               4
 46:     375.16            3               4
 47:     679.84            3               4
 48:      70.55            3               4
 49:    1048.84            3               4
 50:     778.08            3               4
 51:     709.48            3               4
 52:      44.79            3               4
 53:    7299.93            1               4
 54:     718.44            3               4
 55:     386.39            3               4
 56:    2140.68            2               4
 57:    1554.99            3               4
 58:     310.18            3               4
 59:     117.78            3               4
 60:    1272.57            3               4
 61:     645.75            3               4
 62:     197.56            3               4
 63:    1086.34            3               4
 64:     145.58            3               4
 65:     403.19            3               4
 66:    2185.76            2               4
 67:     232.36            3               4
 68:     730.05            3               4
 69:    2462.77            2               4
 70:     377.97            3               4
 71:     240.02            3               4
 72:     632.79            3               4
 73:      11.19            3               4
 74:     167.98            3               4
 75:      43.31            3               4
 76:    1255.92            3               4
 77:    2704.71            2               4
 78:     118.68            3               4
 79:     294.55            3               4
 80:    1686.28            3               4
 81:      92.94            3               4
 82:      83.92            3               4
 83:    1756.05            3               4
 84:     255.83            3               4
 85:     264.97            3               4
 86:     586.85            3               4
 87:    1010.53            3               4
 88:     155.03            3               4
 89:     424.47            3               4
 90:     360.04            3               4
 91:     674.85            3               4
 92:      16.24            3               4
 93:     646.67            3               4
 94:     520.71            3               4
 95:    1593.08            3               4
 96:     108.64            3               4
 97:     190.90            3               4
 98:     511.81            3               4
 99:     576.50            3               4
100:    1752.84            3               4
```

I want to plot it where x axis is whichCLuster and y axis is TranAmount ,now my code for that is

```
dd <-  ggplot(data=data,aes(x=whichCLuster,y=TranAmount,color=whichCLuster))
dd+ geom_point()
```

which gives me an plot  which is close to what I need[image]
but I also want to include no of Items entries per cluster in the plot .I can get the informations by this ,but not sure where to plot this ,and how ,Please assist

```
> data[,.N,whichCLuster]
   whichCLuster    N
1:            3 2024
2:            1  140
3:            2  672
4:            4    3
5:            5   21
```

Comment: How do you want to include the number of items? Like text?

Comment: Yes ,Beside the whichCLuster level .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my attempt to the question. My idea is to add the text indicating the number of observations in each cluster. First, since the `WhichCLuster` is discrete, I found it might be more reasonable to color in discrete scale. Second, I created another data.frame called `df2` which has the information of the total number of observations in each cluster and the median value of `TranAmount`. The median can help us locate the position of the text.

```
# Use the median to get the location of the text
df2 <- df[, .(Total=.N, Median=median(TranAmount)), whichCLuster]

ggplot(df, aes(x=as.factor(whichCLuster), y=TranAmount, color=as.factor(whichCLuster))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data=df2, aes(x=whichCLuster, y=Median, label=Total), hjust=-0.5,
            show.legend=FALSE) +
  scale_color_discrete("WhichCLuster") +
  labs(x="WhichCLuster")
```

[image]

Comment: absolutely what I wanted :) .Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this, but continuing the avenue you're on, you can pass `geom_text` a new aggregated dataset:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=dt, aes(x = whichCLuster, y = TranAmount, color = whichCLuster)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_text(data = dt[, .(.N, height = max(TranAmount)), by = whichCLuster], 
              aes(label = N, x = whichCLuster, y = height), nudge_y = 250)
```

[image: image with labels]

Or put the labels underneath:

```
ggplot(data=dt, aes(x = whichCLuster, y = TranAmount, color = factor(whichCLuster))) + 
    geom_point(show.legend = F) + 
    geom_text(data = dt[, .N, by = whichCLuster], 
              aes(label = N, x = whichCLuster, y = -250), show.legend = F)
```

[image: plot with labels underneath]

---

#### Data

```
dt <- structure(list(TranAmount = c(344.96, 244.15, 342.23, 44.77, 
    8052.48, 184.78, 11.19, 1355.71, 1162.07, 461.95, 83.97, 344.37, 
    648.03, 2122.39, 295.29, 474.32, 2111.72, 950.63, 1246.47, 138.79, 
    917.79, 112, 378.65, 47.57, 5610, 1453.69, 1058.01, 955.77, 277.07, 
    861.53, 296.76, 465.04, 159.65, 3625.25, 197.08, 162.38, 1460.08, 
    438.74, 564.15, 389.44, 1924.62, 190.39, 565.41, 78.39, 2926.92, 
    375.16, 679.84, 70.55, 1048.84, 778.08, 709.48, 44.79, 7299.93, 
    718.44, 386.39, 2140.68, 1554.99, 310.18, 117.78, 1272.57, 645.75, 
    197.56, 1086.34, 145.58, 403.19, 2185.76, 232.36, 730.05, 2462.77, 
    377.97, 240.02, 632.79, 11.19, 167.98, 43.31, 1255.92, 2704.71, 
    118.68, 294.55, 1686.28, 92.94, 83.92, 1756.05, 255.83, 264.97, 
    586.85, 1010.53, 155.03, 424.47, 360.04, 674.85, 16.24, 646.67, 
    520.71, 1593.08, 108.64, 190.9, 511.81, 576.5, 1752.84), whichCLuster = c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L), smallestCluster = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("TranAmount", 
    "whichCLuster", "smallestCluster"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("data.table", 
    "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x102804778>)
```

Comment: thanks it works but in my case the counts overlaps with the points ,how do I fix this

Comment: Again, there's lots of ways, but you can adjust the `nudge_y` value to move the text up or down.

Answer (score 1):

> ggplot(df) +
>   geom_point(aes(x=factor(whichCluster),y=TranAmount,col=factor(whichCluster)))
>   +
>   geom_point(data=df[,.N,by=whichCluster],aes(x=factor(whichCluster),
>   y=N,col=factor(whichCluster)))